# Z3Py Bool variables cast to Int in the model

Tags: int, boolean, z3, z3py

I am using the python API for Z3 to build a tool for my research. I am having the following issue:
I am generating a set of Z3 constraints using a Python script. Since the set might be inconsistent, I am tracking each formula using assert_and_check. For example,

```
s.assert_and_track(occWrites_1== True, 'p16')
```

Of course, occWrites is declared to be Boolean:

```
occWrites_1 = Bool('occWrites_1')
```

However, in the model, Z3 reports occWrites as an Integer. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the value of occWrites in the model be either True or False?

Comment: Please provide a link to a minimal example hosted on rise4fun that demonstrates the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem you described.
In the following example, the value of occWrites_1 is `true` in the model produced by Z3.
It is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/RRBlb).
Note that, the value is a Z3 expression, and it is not a Python `True` value. Perhaps this is the source of the confusion.
The method `sexpr()` pretty prints the value using the Z3 internal format.

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
occWrites_1 = Bool('occWrites_1')
s.assert_and_track(occWrites_1 == True, 'p16')
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m[occWrites_1]
print m[occWrites_1].sexpr()
```

The produced output is:

```
sat
True
true
```